# Locale setting of importxml function in google sheet not working

Tags: google-sheets, locale

I'm trying to extract prices from bookdepositary site in local currency. However, it always retrieves the USD prices no matter what I am trying.

A specific example is:

=IMPORTXML("https://www.bookdepository.com/1/9783836519885";"//span[@class='sale-price']";"bg-BG")

gives US$47.63 no matter that Google sheet settings are changed to Bulgarian and despite of the locale set to "bg-BG".

The same US$47.63 result is retrieved when I use another scrap method like:
=IMPORTXML("https://www.bookdepository.com/1/9783836519885";"//meta[@itemprop='price']/@content";"bg-BG")

The following does not retrieve any result (but this is a secondary problem I am investigating which will follow once I understand the locale problem):
=IMPORTXML("https://www.bookdepository.com/1/9783836519885";"/html/body/div[2]/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/span[1]";"bg-BG")

What do you think - is there a workaround?

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that can be done with `importXML()`.

The [function help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342) seems to be missing the `locale` parameter, but the formula editor inline help box tells the following:

> `locale`: A language and region locale code to use when *parsing* the data. If unspecified, the document locale will be used.

The `importXML()` function only finds data that actually appears in the XML document. The endpoint you mention seems to adjust its content per the client's IP address, but in each response, it only has prices in one currency.

The `locale` parameter does not change the IP address the request is sent from. It gets sent from one of Google's servers, most of which are in the United States. When you set the `locale` parameter, the content may get parsed in a different way, but that will not magically make additional content appear in the page.

Comment: it is strange that this could not be done with importXML() since it could be done with (the paid) importfromweb() where you could set the locale parameter and the magic is done

Comment: That add-on was probably developed specifically to provide functionality not available in the (mostly) free Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, what you actually need is to fool google sheet to not default out on the "common path"

you need something like: https://www.4everproxy.com/ (but with Bulgarian support)
here is some example...

where:

[image]

and then the formula will be from:

[image]

```
=IMPORTXML("https://de.4everproxy.com/direct/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuYm9va2RlcG9zaXRvcnkuY29tLzEvOTc4MzgzNjUxOTg4NQ--","//span[@class='sale-price']")
```

[image]

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks!  Anyway, it is a little bit hard for me to find a suitable BG proxy (maybe I just lack the necessary experience), but it seems that if I want to scrap prices from multiple pages of this site, getting a proxy version for each page will be a little bit burdensome...